# PHP mail() sends 2 copies

Tags: php, function, email

I have this problem with my contact form. When I submit the form I receive 2 identical emails in my box.

Im using JS to check the form for errors and then simple PHP mail() function to send the email.

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php

$from = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$to = "myemail@gmail.com";

$subject = "Contact Form";
$name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$number = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['number']));
$message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));

    $body = "";
    $body .= "Name: ";
    $body .= $name;
    $body .= "\n\n";
    $body .= "E-mail: ";
    $body .= $email;
    $body .= "\n\n";
    $body .= "Telephone Number: ";
    $body .= $number;
    $body .= "\n\n";
    $body .= "Message: ";
    $body .= $message;
    $body .= "\n\n";

    $success = mail($to, $subject, $body, "From: <$from>" . "\r\n" . "Reply-to: <$from>" . "\r\n" . "Content-type: text; charset=utf-8");

?>
```

And here is the JS:

```
$(".submit").click(function() {
        var name = $("input[name=name]").val();
        var email = $("input[name=email]").val();
        var number = $("input[name=number]").val();
        var message = $("textarea[name=message]").val();

        if (defaults['name'] == name || name == "") {
            $(".error").text("Please enter your name!");
            return false;

        } else if (defaults['email'] == email || email == "") {
            $(".error").text("Please enter your email!");
            return false;

        } else if (defaults['number'] == number || number == "") {
            $(".error").text("Please enter your number!");
            return false;

        } else if (defaults['message'] == message || message == "") {
            $(".error").text("Plese enter your message!");
            return false;
        }

        var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&number=' + number + '&message=' + message;
        $(".error").text("Please wait...").hide().fadeIn("fast");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "contact.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function() {
                $('#form form').html("");
                $('#form form').append("<div id='success'>Your message has been sent! Thank you</div>");
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

And here is the HTML form:

```
<form id="contact" method="post" action="#">

<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" required tabindex="1">

<label for="email">Email adress:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" required tabindex="2">

<label for="number">Tel. number:</label>
<input type="text" name="number" tabindex="3">

<label for="message">Your message:</label>
<textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="70" required tabindex="4"></textarea>

<input type="checkbox" id="terms" name="terms" value="terms">I agree to the <a href="#">terms</a>

<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit more-info" tabindex="5" value="Send">

<span class="error"></span>

</form>
```

I have been using the same code for all of my contact forms and it worked all right. Could it be hosting/server related issue?

Comment: Did you check it in Firebug etc.? Does POST request send once or twice?

Comment: nothing is wrong in the code.. do this in the code for testing purpose `$body .= "\n\n"; $body .= rand(1000000,9999999);` and check if the number in both emails are same or diff?

Comment: Try to log each request in a log file `file_put_contents('log.txt', date('h:i') . '\n', FILE_APPEND);` and then check if there are two similar times

Comment: @Adam Thanks for the tip. I didnt know it was possible to check this way. There are 2 POST requests. Here is the image http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/6573/3ax7.jpg

Comment: If you're using Chrome, press F12. You can find in the network tab the list of the requests

Comment: can you show the html markup for the form?

Comment: Try to replace `$(".submit").click(function() {` with `$(".submit").click(function(event) {` and add before `return false;` this `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: @zzlalani Thanks. I did that and I get 2 different numbers. First email: 4439335. Second email: 3221721

Comment: @Matteo It doesnt seem to work. Still 2 POST requests and 2 emails.

Comment: Strange... for some reason the `click` event is fired twice..

Comment: What does the HTML look like. Having `.submit` as a selector could be problematic since it's very general. It could be assigned twice somehow. Have you tried selecting by `#id` attribute?

Comment: @Bart I have added the HTML for the form in the question.

Comment: @Matteo In jQuery events, `return false` is the same as both `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Try to change the input type to `button`

Comment: Put a `console.log` or `alert` immediately **before** `$(".submit").click(function() {` - I have a hunch that you're setting the event twice, and they both get fired on click.  The `return false` should stop the second one, but it's worth checking.

Comment: @Izkata console.log of what? Sorry.

Comment: @Matteo changing to button didnt work.

Comment: @user2850636 Absolutely anything.  It's just an easy way to check if that section of code is run twice.

Comment: console.log("yo"); and this is the result: http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/3134/mmru.jpg. So it is executed 2 times.

Comment: @user2850636 great now in your success block comment `$('#form form').html("");` and check if this `"<div id='success'>Your message has been sent! Thank you</div>"` appears twice or not?

Comment: @zzlalani Where? Because when the email is sent there is only 1 div with the message. Also when I check with dev tools or firebug.

Comment: just do alert after `success: function() {` `alert('test')` may be and check how many times it alerts?

Comment: also write `alert` with in the click event `$(".submit").click(function() {`

Comment: and let us know the results.

Comment: Im getting this error: Method Not Allowed

The requested method POST is not allowed for the URL /kontakt.html.

Comment: @zzlalani When dealing with events, `console.log` is safer than `alert` - if a dialog is opened, sometimes an event won't fire, and you end up with the code doing something differently

Comment: Is the `<script>` tag for your JS in the HTML file somewhere?  Altering the DOM (such as with `.html('')`) could cause inline javascript to fire a second time

Comment: @zzlalani Okay so now I removed the others alerts and did this: success: function() {
    $('#form form').html("");
    $('#form form').append("<div id='success'>Your message has been sent!</div>");

    alert('ajax tests');
} And I received 2 alerts and then the email(s) were sent. But now when I try again I dont get alerts at all. But I didnt check the box to prevent the page from popups.

Comment: so how many times the alert appears? one or two?

Comment: @Izkata yes, im including the js like this in the contact.html: <script src="js/functions.js"></script>

Comment: @user2850636 Sorry, I meant, is it near the `<form>` tags?  Something like that in an entirely different part of the page ought to be fine.

Comment: @Izkata No its in the head actually.

Comment: ok now try this `$('.submit').unbind('click').click(function() {` rather of `$(".submit").click(function() {` and check what happens.. something is wrong in your javascript code out side of this click event

Comment: @zzlalani And what about the rest of the function?

Comment: leave erything as it is just replace the first line `$(".submit").click(function() {` with `$('.submit').unbind('click').click(function() {` and everything else will be untouched.

Comment: Wow, that seems to be working. So what was the problem? I mean because I use this same code all the time and didnt have this problem. Also how could I thank you? Make this an answer so I can choose it as best answer. If there is anything else I can do, please mention it. Since Im new user here and dont know the drill :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19257034/829533 here you go

Comment: @zzlalani Thank you. I already chose the best answer. Is there any way to make the code better? To maybe get rid of this problem or prevent others? And one more question, how can I skip to next line in the comment box? Because enter will just send it. Thanks :)

Comment: For that you have to show us the complete code .. btw it is the best practice to review your complete code when ever you are free. You will end up solving your problems by your self..

Comment: And for comment i think there is no way to move to new line  but you can write everything in notepad and paste it here

Comment: @zzlalani Is there a PM option on this site? Im kind of newbie in these stuff, I dont know what half of those lines even do. I didnt write the code myself. Yeah, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your click event

```
$(".submit").click(function() {
```

with

```
$('.submit').unbind('click').click(function() {
```

code.

What I can assume your click event is binding two times may be due to a lot of the mess in the code

also use this line in the end of the click event function

```
$('.submit').unbind('click').click(function() {

    // your stuff

    event.stopImmediatePropagation(); // as long as not bubbling up the DOM is ok?
});
```

for reference have a look at the link: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-executes-twice-after-ajax

Comment: So in the end it will look like this: `$('.submit').unbind('click').click(function(event) { and then at the end:    event.preventDefault();
 event.stopImmediatePropagation();

Answer (score 2):

`$(".submit").click(function(e) { ... })` POSTS to your server for the first time.

Because this is a `<submit>` button, the form will still submit. The form POSTS to your server for the second time.

The solution would be adding a `e.preventDefault()` at the bottom inside the `$(".submit").click` function...

```
$(".submit").click(function(e) {
    //                      ^ add this e
    var name = ...;

    $.ajax({
        ...
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This has been suggested already but it doesnt fix the issue. There are still 2 POST requests and 2 mails received.

Comment: The form has `action="#"`, so I seriously doubt that can cause it

Comment: Oh hmm. I'll fiddle around and see if the `return false` is really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the jQuery animations:

```
$(".error").text("Please wait...").hide().fadeIn("fast");
```

They can sometimes cause problems.